# Can I restore the shine on laminate flooring?

Tags: flooring, laminate

I've had laminate flooring (Pergo) for several years and is now so dull, it looks like my floor is dirty all the time.  Can I put shine on it like Clean and Gleam from Melaleuca?  I know it has to replaced at some point, but I'm not ready to do that yet.

Comment: It shouldn't be dull after "several" years. I installed Pergo in my mother's back entry 15 years ago and it looks new. Does it just need a proper cleaning? You can clean thoroughly and use a product designed for laminate flooring. https://homeguides.sfgate.com/polish-laminate-floors-36957.html

Comment: I have always used a cleaner specific to laminate flooring.  I've even washed it on my hands and knees with vinegar and water, but it still doesn't have the luster it once had.

Comment: It could be the « traffic » it gets... kids and or pets...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of the dulled surface might help us help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: as long as it's not worn through the veneer, yes. a semi or gloss polyurethane will add shine and protection. a water-based one should adhere just fine, but try a small area in a closet corner first...